# why my animation creation java code don't work in my android project?

Tags: java, android

in fact my button instantly is made blue and then i see x & y values in Toast messages !
how i can see the animation of changing scale ??

```
    Button B = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    B.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            // I want to create a scale animation for a button on this for loop
            float x , y;
            for(x = (float) 1.0 ,  y = (float) 1.0 ; x < (float) 2.0 && y < (float) 2.0 ; x += (float) 0.1 , y += (float) 0.1){
                view.setScaleX(x);
                view.setScaleY(y);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Float.toString(x) + " " + Float.toString(y), 5).show();
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {}
                }, 100);
            }
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            view.setScaleX((float)1.0);
            view.setScaleY((float)1.0);
        }
    });
```

Thanks to the previous

Comment: Does your toast ever say that `x` or `y` have a value greater than `1`?

Comment: Yes, toast say that values is 1 , 1.2 , 1.3 , 1.4 , ... . but I think that my solution is not a common way to solve this problem. Maybe because I am a beginner :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is incorrect.

For animations you need to use classes which are intended for animations.
As example scale animation looks like this:

```
ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(1, 0.5, 1, 0.5);
scaleAnimation.setDuration(3000);
scaleAnimation.setFillAfter(true)
view.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);
```

Comment: OK, perfect! Thanks to Josef E. And Eldar Mensutov because of their care :-)